# how can i get the user data or info according to its student id?

Tags: php

the flow goes like this, login(login.php)->change password(changepass.php), where every user must change their password->redirect on the homepage(homepage.php)where user can view his/her accnt details....what i want on my homepage is that, to greet the user according to its info or studentid with its complete name, but only i could show is the student id of the user as i echo the session. heres my code for my homepage.php

```
       <?php session_start(); ?>
       <?php require('connect/connect.php'); ?>
       <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"                 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
       <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>Home Page</title>


    <link href="mm_spa.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      </head>

         <body class="oneColElsCtrHdr">

      <td width="487" valign="top">

    <?php
    // this is the session id where i could only get from the user(student id)
echo $_SESSION['username'];
$voter = $_SESSION['username'];
function getuserinfo($info){

$info_select = mysql_query ("SELECT `$info` FROM new_reg_student WHERE studid='$voter'");

     //this is my line 116 which i got an error saying 
     //Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, 
     //resource given in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\homepage.php on line 116
if ($query_get = mysql_query($info_select)) { 

if ($result = mysql_result($query_get, 0, $info)) {
return $result;
}
}

}
$fname = getuserinfo('fname');
$lname = getuserinfo('lname');
echo 'hello '. $fname .' '.$lname.'';

   ?>

  </td>
    <div id="footer">
   <p>Footer</p>
    <!-- end #footer --></div>
  <!-- end #container --></div>
   </body>
  </html>
```

heres the preview of my homepage.php

[image: homepage preview]

Answer (score 1):

you are using [mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) twice, so change:

```
$info_select = mysql_query ("SELECT ... ");
```

to

```
$info_select = "SELECT..."; //remove mysql_query from here
if ($query_get = mysql_query($info_select)) { //as you have it here
  ...
```

**Note**: mysql_* is deprecated, instead use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Answer (score 0):

you didn't passed the `studid` into your `getuserinfo($info)` function and in your query you have used `$voter` that you are defined outside into the function, use `global` if you want to access the variable from outside to the function.

```
$voter = $_SESSION['username'];

function getuserinfo($info){

// Call the Student ID
global $voter;

$info_select = "SELECT $info FROM new_reg_student 
                    WHERE studid='".mysql_real_escape_string($voter)."'";

if ($query_get = mysql_query($info_select)) { 
    ......
}
} // Function Close
```

Comment: thank you also for responding, now i could greet my user... =)